# Unable to push the VIEW

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitouch

I've a DashBoard View which has labels and imageViews drawn on it. 
In my application, i want to push the a view which is in StaticPage.h when I touch any ImageView.

I used the concept of UITouch which has method "- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event" as follows:

```
 - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
NSLog(@"touches began");

if ( [touch view] == _icon) {
StaticPage *staticPage = [[StaticPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"StaticPage" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:staticPage animated:YES];
[staticPage release];
}
```

}

where the StaticPage which inherits from UIViewController. 
_icon is a UIImageView.

In the AppDelegate, this method "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions" is as follows:

```
  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[_window addSubview:navController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

where navController is declared in .h file of StaticPage as UINavigationController *navController; and synthesized in .m file of StaticPage.

I wonder why my view from StaticPage is not getting pushed??
Any Help... Thank You in Advance

Comment: navController should not be declared in .h of StaticPage. It should be declared in your main view controller.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Should I declare navController in the class   method from where I want to push the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the navigation but not using method pushViewController:animated. 
Using presentModalViewController:animated we can navigate to the desired page.